# How to solve File has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts', '.js', '.jsx'

Tags: javascript, angular

I am unable to solve this particular error:

> File 'D:/coreui-todo-app/node_modules/multiple-textbox/....' has unsupported extension. The only
> supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts', '.js', '.jsx'.

The solution that I implemented is as follows.

Entering the value of

```
  "allowJs": true
```

in

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
```

However, I am still facing the same issue.

The screenshot attached:

[image]

---

Updated screenshot as suggested by @Pointy to remove .spec.ts  -

[image]

Comment: Well, what extension *does* the file have?

Comment: Which version ?

Comment: @Pointy  --> Please check the screenshot that I have attached. The file has an extension of .ts

Comment: The problem I'm guessing is with those `.spec.ts` files. Typescript doesn't like any extensions other than those listed in the error message.

Comment: @xMayank  --> I have created an npm module and unable to utilize it in my project. It works as an npm but not when installed it in a project. I haven't yet given a version number to the project. Angular cli version --> "@angular/cli": "^9.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0-rc.0",

Comment: @Pointy  --> as suggested by you , I have removed the .spec file but still no difference

Comment: Well unfortunately I don't know enough about Typescript to know what exactly it thinks a "file extension" is.

Comment: Please enter into the mentioned folder (lib/multiple-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

tsconfig.json has an unsupported extension

I solved it by adjusting my script.

```
tsc-watch --compiler typescript/bin/tsc
```

And removed the tsconfig.json from the command.